# Dwork's proof of rationality of zeta function, crux of his generalization of a result of Borel along the way

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-analysis

In this article by Katz and Tate [here](http://www.ams.org/notices/199903/mem-dwork.pdf), there's a nice account of Dwork's argument for showing the rationality of the zeta function part of the Weil conjectures. Here is an excerpt.

> To recapitulate, we now know that the zeta function as power series has integer coefficients and that it is the ratio of two $p$-adically entire functions. We also know the zeta function has a nonzero radius of archimedean convergence (since we have the trivial archimedean bound $N_d \le (q^d - 1)^n$). **Bernie's third new idea is to generalize a classical but largely forgotten result of E. Borel to show that *any* power series with these three properties is a rational function.** Thus he proves the rationality of the zeta function.

Can anybody give a sketch of the argument for this "third new idea"? What is the crux of the proof of Dwork's generalization of Borel's result that any power series with the aforementioned three properties is a rational function? What is the intuition behind the proof, what are the key steps that the proof boils down to?

Comment: The intuition is the product formula in number fields, which by Cauchy's derivative estimate implies immediately that the polynomials are the only $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[[X]]$ holomorphic in the $v$-adic disk of radii $R_v$ satisfying $\prod_v R_v > 1$. Borel's and Dwork's ideas were that the same persists with 'polynomial' and 'holomorphic' replaced by 'rational' and 'meromorphic,' which is a lot more interesting. You may find here a sketch (and reference) of Andre's extension to polydisks:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206450/is-there-a-multivariate-analog-of-dworks-theorem/206463#206463

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Is it possible you could expand on this into a complete answer?

Comment: Have you tried to read the proof anywhere first? Asking for the crux of the proof and the key steps without trying to read the proof seems backwards, particularly in this case when the proof is treated in multiple places. Besides Dwork's original paper (where the notation might seem unwieldy since it is not the notation used today) there is the last chapter of  Koblitz's GTM on p-adic analysis and also chapter II of "An Introduction to $G$-Functions" by Dwork, Gerotto, and Sullivan.

Comment: @KConrad I have already perused Dwork's original paper and the last chapter of Koblitz, but I am interested in another opinion.

Comment: Terry Tao also has a very nice blog post https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/dworks-proof-of-rationality-of-the-zeta-function-over-finite-fields/

Comment: The question seems to demand an awful lot which is not very well defined. Asking for someone to write an explanation is, in my view, significantly more vague than saying "I don't understand this part of Dwork's paper" or "is there a connection between Dwork's paper and these other things I've read about"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you read [Dwork's paper](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/4d614105-26d3-487f-92b9-6f0b199fc06f/cb0b02f3ddfa9cea015df533e6623724) - it is quite clear (see p. 643)?

Comment: A downvote? Why?

Comment: I am not the down-voter, but it strikes me that answering a question with a one sentence pointer to a fairly obvious reference presumes that the OP has made no effort to find an answer to the question him or herself.  If this is is the case (as it often is) then the question does not meet the standards laid out in the help center and it should be modified or closed.  Otherwise the OP is looking for guidance or intuition which may not be easily found in the literature.  In either case, the one sentence answer is not particularly helpful or constructive.

Comment: @PaulSiegel I thought Dwork was quite lucid in his paper (this is not always true in original references), which is why I gave a pointer to it. In addition, the argument is not so long.

Comment: @PaulSiegel It isn't clear to me **what** guidance the OP is looking for; the OP wants an explanation, but doesn't say what requires explanation

Comment: @YemonChoi I'm inclined to agree with your assessment, but in that case the question should probably be rewritten or closed rather than answered.  And if a good answer is possible it would probably not take the form of a one sentence pointer to the original paper.  (Though I will concede to Igor Rivin that there are cases where that can be a good answer to a good question.)